# HTML table producing duplicate border lines at the top

Tags: css, html

Why is my table producing duplicate border lines at the top

```
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Car detail</td>
  </tr>
<?php do { ?>
    <tr>  
      <td>
      <?php echo $row_Recordset1['make']; ?> 
      <?php echo $row_Recordset1['carmodel']; ?> 
      <?php echo $row_Recordset1['car_number']; ?>
     </td>   
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have something like empty results in $Recordset1?

Comment: what is in `<?php echo $row_Recordset1['make']; ?>` can you add here php of $row_Recordset?

Comment: @silviagreen I have relized the problem. There are empty lists. This makes me feel like an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are empty rows in your table

Comment: yes i found that to be the issue and so i had to change the php code to eliminate empty results

Answer (score 1):

The "double-border" is the standard look, and with border="1" you set the line width of the border. In this case what you need is "border-collapse:collapse", wich will result in a single lined border.

You can find more details here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: If the problems are the two empty rows then the upper answer should be correct. (However the question is talking about borders. :D )

Comment: That wasn't the issue. but at least that is something new that  i have known.